# Convergence rate of the power method for finding eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, limits, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ be a real-valued square matrix with an eigenvector $w$ strictly larger (in absolute value of the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$) than all others, and let $v$ be any vector not orthogonal to $w$.  The power method says that
$$\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \lambda^{-k}M^kv = w$$
I am curious about the convergence rate of this process.  Can we bound
$$\max \limits_i |(M^k v)_i - w_i|$$
 as a function of $k, v, w,$ or perhaps the other eigenvalues of $M$?

Comment: Your limit statement is not correct.  I think you want to say $\lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda^{-k} M^k v = w$, where the largest eigenvalue is $\lambda$.

Comment: It's still not quite right.  First of all, the limit should be an eigenvector for $\lambda$, but not necessarily $w$: it could equally well be $t \lambda$ for some real $t$.  Second, unless $M$ happens to be a symmetric matrix the condition is not orthogonality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has algebraic multiplicity $1$.  Then we have
$\mathbb R^n = U \oplus \mathbb R w$ where $M U \subseteq U$ and the restriction $M|_U$ has spectral radius $r < |\lambda|$: $r$ is the maximum absolute value
of the other eigenvalues of $M$.  Then for any vector $v$, 
$v = u + t w$ with $u \in U$ and $t \in \mathbb R$, and
$$|  \| \lambda^{-k} M^k v - t w \|_\infty 
= \|\lambda^{-k} M^k u\|_\infty \le |\lambda|^{-k} \|M^{k}\| \|u\|_\infty$$ 
where $\|M^k\|$ is the operator norm of $M^k$ induced by the $\infty$ norm on $\mathbb R^n$.
The spectral radius $r = \lim_{k \to \infty} \|M^k\|^{1/k}$, so
for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\|M^k\| < (r + \epsilon)^k$ for sufficiently large $k$.
Thus for sufficiently large $k$,
$$\max_i |(\lambda^{-k} M^k v- t w)_i| \le \left(\dfrac{r+\epsilon}{|\lambda|}\right)^k \|u\|_\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

The convergence rate depends on the ratio of the largest eigenvalue to the second largest. See the [analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration#Analysis) here. Basically, the worst case scenario is when $w$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the second largest eigenvalue.